# how to get group ID and set it in assigned to in SingleTask

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, visual-studio

I´m trying to collect Group ID to use it in Assigned to field... I´m using VS 2015 and SP 2013, I´ve a Owner column in my list.
 here u can see my workflow 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
what I miss?? or what I need to Change??

Comment: Have you tried using the group's name instead?

Comment: Yes and it's work fine but i dont need to hardcoding groups...when I create an item in the list and select a group would workflow identify which group it is and send Emil

Comment: You mean you want the workflow to identify which group the current user belongs to and send the group an email? What if they belong to more than one group?

Comment: no, I mean to identify the group based on what user set for group in the owner column and then send Email to this group

Comment: In your `GetDynamicValueProperties` activity, are you taking the value of the  of the Owner column? Can you share the screenshot for the properties of the `GetDynamicValueProperties`?

Comment: @Submits I put it with other images in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41490/discussion-between-submits-and-milad-francis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the `Assigned to` field won't accept the user group's ID and would need another property. So I would suggest this:

- After the `GetDynamicValueProperties` activity, add a `LookupSPGroup` activity
- In the Properties of this activity in the `GroupPrincipalId` property add your `OwnerId` variable. Set the result property to any variable of your choice (it should be of `DynamicValue` data type)
- Now on the `LookupSPGroup` activity click the Get Properties link, which will automatically add another `GetDynamicValueProperties` activity. In this activity, in the Path column, try a different property, which you will then need to use in the `Assigned to` field. Try `LoginName` or `Title` or one of the other properties
- If none of these properties work try using the `Users` property, which will return an `SPUserCollection`. Then go through these users and add their Login Names to the `Assigned to` field individually
- The other alternative that I can think of is to use the `HTTPSend` activity to make a REST call to this end point: http://yoursiteurl/_api/web/sitegroups(yourgroupid)/users. This will return a collection of users which, again, you could take the IDs or Login Names from and try entering these into your `Assigned to` field

I hope this sets you on the correct path.

Comment: Great :) Just out of curiosity, which property worked for you?

Comment: the first one with LookupSPGroup

Comment: Which property? `LoginName`, `Title`?

Comment: Title property!